# open-circuited stub VS stepped-impedance

Tags: filter, low-pass, microwave, microstrip

What is the difference between open-circuited stub and stepped-impedance ?

> The open-circuited stub microstrip realization method is a
>   modification of the stepped-impedance microstrip realization method.
>   It approximates the series inductance as a high impedance transmission
>   line while the shunt capacitance effect is simulated by an
>   open-circuited stub using Richard’s transformation.

See [2GHz Microstrip Low Pass Filter Design with Open-Circuited Stub](http://www.iosrjournals.org/iosr-jece/papers/Vol.%2013%20Issue%202/Version-2/A1302020109.pdf)

Comment: This question was also posted on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/rfelectronics/comments/cziedz/opencircuited_stub_vs_steppedimpedance/

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring for a moment that that publication seems to be of very low quality (it reads almost like a student assignment, not like a paper/letter from a scientific publication, and at no point really provides any novelty).

The difference is simple: A stepped impedance is a section where the characteristic impedance changes. This impedance step causes reflections. Creating a short section of such a structure gives rise to resonances, and as a result many of these can be used to build a filter.

A stub is a transmissionline section that is connected to another transmission line.

In the paper linked, the stub is the big piece that goes down, in the middle of the structure (the 11 mm long, 8 mm wide piece). [image: image from paper]

It is an open-circuit stub because the end of it is not connected to anything - it is left open. By doing this, you generate a resonator again (as the waves reflect of the open-circuit end).

In this paper, what they seem to be doing is create a filter from a lumped-circuit model, and then build the lumped elements with microstrip structures - the inductors are made with straight section of transmission line, the stub makes a capacitor.

Comment: Does open-circuited stub also not have impedance change/step ?

Comment: it has a given impedance, but in this case, the simple stub does not have a 'step' - it is constant over the length of the stub.

Comment: Would the intersection between the two thin, horizontal microstrip transmission lines and the open-circuited stub be not contributing to impedance change/step ?

Comment: In a sense, there will likely be some edge-effects that you might be able to interpret that way, which give rise to slight errors. However, when the filter is designed these are usually not taken into account (similar errors are the fringing fields making the open microstrip stub appear a bit longer, etc). 

The design is done with idealized model of transmission lines that have no influence on each others. Usually, you would use a simulator to verify the performance. If the transmision line model would work, people designing software tools for full-3D simulation would be out of a job.